# sort array of strings by a part of these strings

Tags: c#, sorting

I am attempting to sort xls lines by fourth string in lines.

```
string[] list_lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\VS\WriteLines.xls");



        // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of Your Database = ");

        foreach (var line in list_lines)
        {

            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
```

I am having problems creating algorithm that will identify the fourth element of each line and list content in alphabetical order.
The words in each line are separated by ' '.

Can anyone put me on a right direction please?

EDIT--------------------------
ok,

```
foreach (var line in list_lines.OrderBy(line => line.Split(' ')[3]))
```

sorted the problem. Lines are sorted as I need. Excel changes ' ' spaces with ';'. That's why when compiled it was giving error.

Now, I guess, I need to parse each part of string to int since it sorts by first digit and not by a number.

Comment: What do you want to do when a string doesn't have a 4th item, as found in @Patrick Hofman 's answer?

Comment: it's strange. I am sure that xls file is populated in 5 columns

Comment: They are probably being separated by another symbol than space. Have you check the lines while debugging?

Comment: Draken, You were right. It seems that excel puts ';'  on place of empty spaces.

Comment: The lines get sorted by any column I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the lines and then use the third item in an `OrderBy`:

```
foreach (var line in list_lines.OrderBy(line => line.Split(' ')[3]))
{
}
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. Your code doesn't cause error, but when compiled I get strange error and code doesn't work.

Comment: Then not every line has a fourth item.

Comment: they do, there are 5 columns in the file. all populated by numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just *sort* the array:

```
string[] list_lines = ...;

// General case: not all strings have 4 parts
Array.Sort(list_lines, (left, right) => {
  String[] partsLeft = left.Split(' ');
  String[] partsRight = right.Split(' ');

  if (partsLeft.Length < 4)
    if (partsRight.Length < 4)
      return String.Compare(left, right, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    else 
      return -1;
  else if (partsRight.Length < 4)
    return 1; 

  return String.Compare(partsLeft[3], partsRight[3], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
});
```

If all the lines *guaranteed* to have 4 items at least it can be simplfied into

```
Array.Sort(list_lines, (left, right) => 
  String.Compare(left.Split(' ')[3],
                 right.Split(' ')[3],
                 StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```