# Parsing multiple string lines to numbers

Tags: c#, string, parsing, integer

I have such code:

```
string[] list_lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\VS\WriteLines.xls");

System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of Your Database = ");

foreach (var line in list_lines.OrderBy(line => line.Split(';')[3]))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
```

I would like to TryParse the list_lines so they are numbers, not strings.
Is it possible to 'bulk' it somehow?
Each line consists of 5 strings after they are Split.

---

**EDIT**

I wrote this:

```
string[] list_lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\VS\WriteLines.xls");


        int[] newList;
        // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of Your Database = ");
        int.TryParse(list_lines[], out newList);

        foreach (var line in newList.OrderBy(line => line.Split(';')[3]))
        {

            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
```

But I get error on list_lines[] , it says that there must be a value.

Comment: Are you really trying to get `int[]` or you actually just want to order by the result of `line.Split(';')[3]` *as int instead of string*?

Comment: Yes, I want to order result by int not string.

Comment: So it seems that people are getting the question wrong (or maybe I am). Check my answer below, and see if it is what you meant to do.

Comment: I thought that in order to sort I need to get int. I didn't realize there is easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595802/sort-array-of-strings-by-a-part-of-these-strings), it seems that you want to order the lines by *the 3rd split result as `int`*, then you can do this way :

```
foreach (var line in list_lines.OrderBy(line => 
                                {
                                    int lineNo;
                                    var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[3], out lineNo);
                                    if(success) return lineNo;
                                    return int.MaxValue;
                                }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
}
```

I'm using `int.MaxValue` as default for when `TryParse` fails. This way, failed lines will come last. You can change the default to `int.MinValue` instead, if you want the failed lines to come first.

By the way, C# naming convention uses *camel-case* for variables, like `lineNo` and `listLines` instead of `line_no` and `list_lines`.

---

To get `int[]` that corresponds to each line, you can use similar logic, but now in a `Select()` method instead of `OrderBy()` :

```
int[] newList = list_lines.Select(line => 
                            {
                                int lineNo;
                                var success = int.TryParse(line.Split(';')[3], out lineNo);
                                if(success) return lineNo;
                                return int.MaxValue; //or whatever default value appropriate
                            })
                           .ToArray();
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot! I will study the code now to get into understanding what was done here. And yes, I forgot about the c# convention here. I will rename vars with _ .

Comment: I guess for now this is what I need. But in the future I would like also be able to make calculations on these string-to-integer values, and not only ordering and this is where int comes handy and necessary

Comment: @paddy See the 2nd code snippet above for a way to get the array of `int`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the list.

```
list_lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(';')).Select(cell => int.Parse(cell));
```

If there can be non-number cells and you are looking for positive numbers you can add a `Where` clause

```
list_lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(';')).Where(cell => cell.All(@char => char.IsDigit(@char))).Select(cell => int.Parse(cell));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
int number;
var intList = list_lines.Select(s => s.Split(';')
                                      .Where(p => Int32.TryParse(p, out number))
                                      .Select(y => Int32.Parse(y)))
                                      .SelectMany(d=>d).ToList();
```